# Modificar un array de int en un array de float para una multiplicación en Python

Tags: python, numpy

Hola traigo multiplicar matrices de `int` convertida en `float` pero no funciona ni la modificación ni la multiplicación.

Este es el código:

```
self.item_vecs[i,:].astype(float)
self.item_vecs[i, :] += self.learning_rate * \
                          (e * self.user_vecs[u, :] - \
                           self.item_fact_reg * self.item_vecs[i,:])
```

Me responde :

> ```
> <ipython-input-79-01697da52e60> in sgd(self)
>     174             self.item_vecs[i,:].astype(float)
>     175             print self.item_vecs[i,:]
> --> 176             self.item_vecs[i, :] += self.learning_rate *                                     (e * self.user_vecs[u, :] -                                     
> self.item_fact_reg * self.item_vecs[i,:])
>     177 
>     178     def predict(self, u, i):
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc add output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
> ```

Aquí están los elementos utilisados :

> ```
> self.learning_rate : 
> 0.001
> e :  0.0
> self.user_vecs[u, :] : 
> [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
> self.item_fact_reg :  0.0
> self.item_vecs[i,:] : 
> [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que nunca realizas la conversión. Aplicas el cambio de tipo sobre una fila, esto retorna un array con los datos de esa fila con el tipo especificado, pero **no se cambia el tipo en el array original**. Además, no es posible cambiar el tipo a una fila o columna de un array de NumPy ya que su **tipado ha de ser homogéneo en todo el array**. Lo que debes hacer es cambiar el tipo al array completo:

```
 self.item_vecs = self.item_vecs.astype('float64')
 self.item_vecs[i, :] += self.learning_rate * 
                      (e * self.user_vecs[u, :] - 
                       self.item_fact_reg * self.item_vecs[i,:])
```